# create new tenant in multiple tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, aspnetboilerplate

[image]

[image]

When I create new Tenant in Debug mode and on public api only login dc tenant in correct mode even though connection string configuration to server in app settings is same.

Please show me how to fix it!

i use framework abp boilerplate

Comment: endcode connectionstring : var tenant = ObjectMapper.Map<Tenant>(input);
            tenant.ConnectionString = input.ConnectionString.IsNullOrEmpty()
                ? null
                : SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Encrypt(input.ConnectionString);

            var defaultEdition = await _editionManager.FindByNameAsync(EditionManager.DefaultEditionName);
            if (defaultEdition != null)
            {
                tenant.EditionId = defaultEdition.Id;
            }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That framework has different enconde key for Debug and no Debug, but it always return true, so I changed this file:

```
 namespace eTrans.Debugging
 {
    public static class DebugHelper
    {
       public static bool IsDebug
       {
          get
          {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).